# How to add JS file reference in a custom JS file

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

In a custom module `view/frontend/web/js` folder I have 2 JS files:

`jquery.custom.js`
`registration.js`

In the XML layout file of the module, I have:

```
<head>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/jquery.custom.js"/>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/registration.js"/>
</head>
```

Inside the third party library `jquery.custom.js` file there is a function called `$.validateData`. This library works since I use it everywhere in my projects (so there is no an issue with `$.validateData` function definition). The problem is when trying to use it in Magento.

This is `registration.js` file content:

```
requirejs([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/mage',
    ], function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validateData',
            function (value) {
                return $.validateData(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('Data is incorrect.')
        );
    });
```

When I load the page and the custom validation is run, a javascript error is shown telling that `$.validateData is not found`.

I think that the problem is because I am referencing the third party library incorrectly, so, the question is, how can I reference it correctly? I should add it in the `requirejs` array? how?

I tried to add that library in the `registration.js` file this way:

```
requirejs([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/mage',
        'Vendor_Module/js/jquery.custom.js'
    ], function ($) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validateData',
            function (value) {
                return $.validateData(value);
            },
            $.mage.__('Data is incorrect.')
        );
    });
```

But in this case, this other error is shown:

```
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Vendor_Module/js/jquery.custom.js
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

what is missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you try after replacing your `$` with `jQuery` everywhere, sometimes $ conflicts with php.
Your registration.js will look like

```
requirejs([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/ui',
        'jquery/validate',
        'mage/translate',
        'mage/mage',
    ], function (jQuery) {
        jQuery.validator.addMethod(
            'validateData',
            function (value) {
                return jQuery.validateData(value);
            },
            jQuery.mage.__('Data is incorrect.')
        );
    });
```

Also do inspect element then go to network tab then check that registration.js file is actually included in that page or not. You may need to press ctrl+r to reload the webpage to see all included files.
If you found .js file is included but still code not working then try to use on ready and onload functions also, examples are -

```
require([ 'jquery'], function($){ $(document).ready(function($) { //your code }); });
```

And

```
require([ 'jquery' , 'dotdotdot' , 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        //custom js code
        /* $(".product-item-name").each(function(){
            $(this).dotdotdot(); 
        }); */
    });
});
```

Thanks Vibhore

Comment: Hello,,,, by analising the console window I could conclude that the JS `jquery.custom.js` is not loaded correctly due to missing `jquery` library. If I don't reference it in the `requirejs` function and include it in the `<head>` element of the layout, the error shown in console is `jQuery is not defined`. I tried by linking the `jquery.custom.js` file after `registration.js` but the same happen. How can I ensure jquery library is loaded first? I thought that `requirejs` does that, but it seems it does not.

Comment: Hello, finally I got it to work. I should create a `requiredjs-config.js` file. That way I created the `jquery` dependency for the custom JS.